# Extract error details from Triggered Sends?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I have a triggered send where I can see a number of error'd sends in the queue. Is there a way I can reveal for which triggers these failed for? or is there an API call I can I make to export these?

(fyi the trigger is from Triggered Sends in Marketing Cloud connect, so I cannot check the response from a triggered send request)

Comment: This is related to Marketing Cloud, not apex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a Not Sent tracking extract, specifying the JobID for your send in order to see the "Reason" why those records were not sent. More info on the possible Reasons can be found at [this link](https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_send_error_codes.htm&type=5).

To do this in the SFMC UI, create an automation with the first step being a Tracking Extract. In the config area of the extract, specify your JobID as the SendID and uncheck all boxes except "Not Sent". Then you'll need a file transfer activity to move the zip file from the safehouse to your FTP.